# SQL Server - Select from a variable amount of tables depending on date range

Tags: sql-server

I have a query that joins multiple Data Sources together, I need a query that will select from a variable amount of tables depending on the date range I send it.

**Joining Query**

```
SELECT I.SerialNumber as DataSource,Deployed,Removed
  FROM InstrumentDeployments ID
  INNER JOIN Instruments I On I.Id = ID.InstrumentId
  INNER JOIN Points P On P.Id = ID.PointId
  WHERE P.Id = 1
  ORDER BY Deployed
```

**Joining Query Result**

[image: JoingingTable]

So from the above query result, if I wanted to select all of the historical information, it would go through and get the data from the specific tables 
 (called DataSource in query above) dependant on the relevant date.

**Final Query** - Something like this but the variable tables from query result above.

```
SELECT * FROM (VariableTables) WHERE DateRange BETWEEN '2016-09-07' and '2018-07-28'
```

Thanks

Comment: Do all the tables have the same columns with the same datatype? Do you want one recordset that unions them all or multiple recordsets?

Comment: Yes all tables have the same columns with same data types. Yes one data set please.

Comment: So first thing that me and everyone else will say is that this is a bad table deisgn - there should be one table with an additional column. Now that's out of the way, I will pose an answer.

Comment: The issue is that we have over 100 of these tables with data going in every minute, the table would grow massively very quickly and we would struggle to query the data so we found it more suitable to split the data in to individual tables.

Comment: Perhaps partitioning would have been a better solution to many different tables.

Comment: @mkb - the problem you describe can be avoided using indexes - if you had a field called 'DataType' to replace the concept of separate tables, and indexed it, you'd get the performance the same as multiple tables.

Comment: OK thank you for your suggestions, this is something we will look in to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please note that this is **completely untested** as the sample data is an image (and I can't copy and paste text from an image). If this doesn't work, please provide your sample data as **`text`**.

Anyway, the only way you'll be able to achieve this is with Dynamic SQL. This also, like in the comments, *assumes* that every table has the **exact** same definition. if it doesn't you'll likely get a failure (perhaps a conversion error, or that for a `UNION` query all tables must have the same number of columns). If they don't, you'll need to explicitly define your columns.

Again, this is untested, however:

```
DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(MAX);

SET @SQL =  STUFF((SELECT NCHAR(10) + N'UNION ALL' + NCHAR(10) +
                          N'SELECT *' + NCHAR(10) +
                          N'FROM ' + QUOTENAME(I.SerialNumber) + NCHAR(10) +
                          N'WHERE DateRange BETWEEN @dStart AND @dEnd'
                   FROM InstrumentDeployments ID
                        INNER JOIN Instruments I ON I.Id = ID.InstrumentId
                        INNER JOIN Points P ON P.Id = ID.PointId
                   WHERE P.Id = 1
                   ORDER BY Deployed
                   FOR XML PATH(N'')),1,11,N'') + N';';
PRINT @SQL; --Your best friend.
DECLARE @Start date, @End date;
SET @Start = '20160907';
SET @End = '20180728';

EXEC sp_executesql @SQL, N'@dStart date, @dEnd date', @dStart = @Start, @dEnd = @End;
```

Comment: If you are providing untested code for OP, then that would be cause problem, However i would replace your keyword `untested` with `assumptions` based on sample data or result.

Comment: @YogeshSharma I actually don't understand what you mean there, sorry. The above code is based on their sample, however, as the sample data is an image, the OP is expecting the volunteers here to retype it to be able to test. That should be something they do, not the volunteers trying to help them. :)